# Use epub to view interactive map

Tags: epub, epub3

I want to create an interactive map, with a main image with many dots, where every dot is linked to an image.
The size of all the images can reach 1 GB, and the files will be stored on the mobile device.
Is it possible to package all the images and the main image into an epub file, so that it can be read with an epub reader, on mobile device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested the size limit.
I created an epub file with 400 images. The size of the epub file is ~700 MB.
fbreader ebook reader, had no problem to open and read the file, on Linux machine.